# Angular 9 Highcharts - when using series of type pie with type gauge the innerSize of pie is not working

Tags: angular, highcharts

After I updated to hicharts v8.0.1. the innerSize of a 'pie' series when used with 'gauge' series is doing nothing. Any solution regarding this?

The only think that seems to work is to downgrate, but I don t want to do this.

```
 pane: {
    center: ['50%', '75%'],
    size: '125%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        connectorWidth: 0,
        style: { fontWeight: 'medium', color: '#4A4A4A' },
        formatter: function(): any {
          return this.point.options.name;
        },
        distance: -1,
        y: -20,
        x: -3,
      },
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      innerSize: '65%',
      center: ['50%', '85%'],

    },
    gauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      dial: {
        radius: this.chartSizeOptions.dialRadius,
      },
    },

  },
  chart: {
    type: 'gauge',
  },
series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '60%',
      size: '140%',
      keys: ['y', 'id', 'color', 'name'],
      data: seriesData,
      enableMouseTracking: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'gauge',
      name: '% over/under goal',
      animation: false,
      data: [this.calculateGaugePoint(goalCostDiffPct)],
    },
  ],
};
```

this is what I need 
[image]

and this is what I got
[image]

I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/ in order to see the issue

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo with your versions ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/ same think is happening here also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a Highcharts bug, so I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13629

The problem occurs since version 8.0.1, so as a workaround you can use version 8.0.0.

Comment: thanks for your answer and for the bug, but as I wrote in my initial post I don t want to downgrate to 8.0.0.

Comment: Hi @Andrei Chivu, Ok, I will try to find some workaround for you.

Comment: As a workaround, you need to overwrite `getCenter` method from pie prototype. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hbzvpuxn/